# XbeeException : Could not find port: /dev/tty.usbserial-A6005uPi

Tags: java, eclipse, xbee

I try to run an example using the API of XBee.

When I execute the program in Eclipse, I obtain this error :

```
Stable Library
=========================================
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
    Jar version = RXTX-2.1-7
    native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
[2015-12-01 08:56:35,652] [main] [ERROR] [com.rapplogic.xbee.examples.ApiAtExample] at command failed 
com.rapplogic.xbee.api.XBeeException: Could not find port: /dev/tty.usbserial-A6005uPi
    at com.rapplogic.xbee.SerialPortConnection.openSerialPort(SerialPortConnection.java:94)
    at com.rapplogic.xbee.SerialPortConnection.openSerialPort(SerialPortConnection.java:61)
    at com.rapplogic.xbee.api.XBee.open(XBee.java:132)
    at com.rapplogic.xbee.examples.ApiAtExample.<init>(ApiAtExample.java:53)
    at com.rapplogic.xbee.examples.ApiAtExample.main(ApiAtExample.java:76)
```

Please, can someone explain what this error means? Can someone help me to find solution?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

. The steps of the solution are :
 1, verify the group of ttyUSB0 :
 ls -la /dev/ttyUSB0
crwxrwx--x 1 root dialout 188, 0 Dec  2 10:01 /dev/ttyUSB0

Then verify if the user "sam" existe in the same group (dialout) in this case :  id -Gn sam
sam adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare  ,

In the case that the user is not in the same group it is primordial to add it  :  sudo usermod -a -G dialout sam

Finaly, change the permission of ttyUSB0 like this :
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0

Now if the example is put to run it will be executed correctly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong pathname to the serial port of your XBee module: `Could not find port: /dev/tty.usbserial-A6005uPi`.

If you look in the dev directory, what are the names of your usbserial ttys?

`ls /dev/tty.usbserial*`

Are you passing that pathname into the program, or is it hard-coded somewhere in the source?  Whatever it is, you just need to update it to the appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks so much :) the name of USB serial is :ttyUSB0 so i change it in the program but when i run, i obtain the same error : Could not find port: /dev/ttyUSB0.

Answer (score 0):

A clue here is perhaps that OP mentions first the problem with device on /dev/tty.usbserial.... which is indicative of using on OSX while the /dev/ttyUSB0 is Linux naming for USB ports, so maybe is running this on a pi?
So a couple of things to check for are:
1. On Mac the hot plugging of FTDI devices is problematic. Search for solutions related to using KEXT to load/unload the right driver.
2. I have found in pi that at random, the USB devices get reassigned so my /dev/ttyUSB0 yesterday might today be my /dev/ttyUSB1 when i have multiple USB devices attached to the hub. If you are not on a Pi but another Linux box check f this happens.

In general when using USB devices there is no reliable enumeration. Do not expect hour by hour or day by day that the USB connection will remain the same. Try using on Windows and watch your COM port number climb as you connect/disconnect the same device.

You can manually enumerate by doing similar to what tomlogic has suggested and always run:
ls /dev/tty* | grep '[usb|USB]' 
so you can see all the tty devices (osx/*nix) that are USB related on your system (the cmd will work on all nix-like systems).